# How do coders select words or parts of lines fast?

Tags: performance, select, copy-paste, effort

As a beginner I would like to know how to fast select a word, line or part of it without dragging+left button, because I see that many people do it effortlessly and fast like they click on a word and drag a bit and it selects all of the word.
I code in c++ and use Embarcadero Devc++

I tried many tips but no one had the effect I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad and unclear, but a couple things about button clicks pop into mind.

You can click, double-click, and triple-click in text in a program.

A single click typically deselects anything else selected.

A double-click might select a word that it double-clicked. If you double-click anywhere in a word, select the entire word.

A tripe-click might select an entire line. So, if triple-clicking in text, the entire line containing the click character might be selected.

At the end of the day, it really depends on what you're trying to do and how "user-friendly" you want the program to bo.